# How to initialize driver once in WebDriver class and then use it to start other classes?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng, selenium-chromedriver

If I have 10 classes in testng.xml, it will open 10 browser sessions.
How can I initialize the driver once and only open one browser for one test case then close and open a window again for the second test case and so on?

I have my driver setup code in a constructor, which is maybe a bad way to approach it? How can I initialize it in TNGDriver class and then use it in Testcase1 class?

I tried using @BeforeClass and have a setUp method but that did not work.

**TNGDriver class**

```
public abstract class TNGDriver {

public static WebDriver driver;
private static String chromeDriverPath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chromedriver.exe";  

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public TNGDriver() {        
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--incognito");
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverPath);        
    driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);    
    driver.manage().window().maximize();            
}

public static WebDriver getDriver() {
    return driver;
}

public static void setDriver(WebDriver driver) {
    TNGDriver.driver = driver;
}
```

**Testcase1 class**

```
public class Testcase1 extends Registration {

    @Test(priority = 1) 
    public void step1_checkSomething() {        
        //do something
    }

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void step2_clickOnSomething() {          
        //click on something            
    }

}
```

**testng.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="AutomationFramework" parallel="false" preserve-order="true">
    <test name="Registration">      
        <classes>
            <class name="regression.Testcase01" />
            <class name="regression.Testcase02" />              
        </classes>      
    </test>             
</suite>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome Driver opens every time private window by default, You don't need this really.

```
//options.addArguments("--incognito");
```

**You can make structure like below :**

```
public class TNGDriver {

public static WebDriver driver;
private static String chromeDriverPath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chromedriver.exe";  

public void DriverConfiguration() {        
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--incognito");  
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverPath);        
    driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);    
    driver.manage().window().maximize();            
}

public void QuitDriver(){
    driver.quit();
}

}
```

**Unit Test cases:**

```
public class Testcase1 extends Registration {

TNGDriver objTND = new TNGDriver();

    @BeforeTest
    public void initializeDriver(){
    objTND.DriverConfiguration();  
    }

    @Test(priority = 1) 
    public void step1_checkSomething() {        
        //do something
    }

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void step2_clickOnSomething() {          
        //click on something            
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void initializeDriver(){
    objTND.QuitDriver();  
    }
}
```

If you want to use browser(to open) before each @Test, You can use this same method with @BeforeMethod annotation.

Comment: Thanks, Ishita!
I did it your way, however, when I try to run testng.xml, it still opens multiple sessions.

Comment: Its depend on how you have configured your TESTNG.XML suite. Please share it in your question.

Comment: Shared it now in the question!

Comment: Remove this : parallel="false" preserve-order="true"

Comment: I removed it but still the same. I think I see the problem. 2 browser sessions open up, then first method of first class is executed, then the first method of the second class is executed, and then it stops. What would be the best way to execute the first test with all its methods and then start the second test? Should I add groups?

Comment: My bad. Please check with @BeforeClass annotation. I forgot negative mark of BeforeTest annotation. It happened similarly to me also.

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much! I added one class per test in testng.xml and now it works properly! Thanks!!!

Comment: You can add multiple classes in single .XML and it will work similarly. Please accept and raised my answer.